# Troubleshooting with internationalisation

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, localization

I recently added other language support to my ios project.
Then, I continued to develop.
Now if I turn my language back to `English` it runs an older (way older) version of the app and I don't know why since the storyboard and code are all correct in the project.
Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I turn my language back to english it runs an older (way older) version of the app

This sort of thing is often caused by having old files lying around in the built app, even if they have been changed in the project. Try following my instructions for cleaning the caches and getting rid of all copies of the build app, here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6247073/341994